# How do I get circe to decode nested json with kebab-case attribute names

Tags: json, scala, circe

I started with the accepted answer to [SO question 53573659](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53573659/need-help-decoding-following-json-with-circe) which has a nested list of attrs and uses the auto-parser to get the data into case classes.  I want to be able to handle the same data but with the nested fields having kebab-case rather than camel case.

Here is the same input JSON with the kebab-case fields

```
val sampleKebab="""{
 "parent" : {
  "name" : "title",
  "items" : [
   {
    "foo" : "foo1",
    "attrs" : {
      "attr-a" : "attrA1",
      "attr-b" : "attrB1"
    }
   },
   {
    "foo" : "foo2",
    "attrs" : {
      "attr-a" : "attrA2",
      "attr-b" : "attrB2",
      "attr-c" : "attrC2"
     }
    }
   ]
  }
}"""
```

I can decode the attrs data by itself using the following example

```
import io.circe.derivation.deriveDecoder
import io.circe.{Decoder, derivation}
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.parser._


 val attrKebabExample = """{
    "attr-a": "attrA2",
    "attr-b": "attrB2",
    "attr-c": "attrC2"
}"""
case class AttrsKebab(attrA: String, attrB: String)
implicit val decoder: Decoder[AttrsKebab] = deriveDecoder(derivation.renaming.kebabCase)
val attrKebabData = decode[AttrsKebab](attrKebabExample)
```

attrKebabData decodes to

```
Either[io.circe.Error,AttrsKebab] = Right(AttrsKebab(attrA2,attrB2))
```

When I try to tie this decoder into the case class hierarchy from the original question, it exposes some glue that I am missing to hold it all together

```
case class ItemKebab(foo: String, attrs : AttrsKebab)
case class ParentKebab(name: String, items: List[ItemKebab])
case class DataKebab(parent : ParentKebab)
case class Data(parent : Parent)
val dataKebab=decode[DataKebab](sample)
```

In this case, dataKebab contains a DecodingFailure

```
Either[io.circe.Error,DataKebab] = Left(DecodingFailure(Attempt to decode value on failed cursor, List(DownField(attr-a), DownField(attrs), DownArray, DownField(items), DownField(parent))))
```

My guess is that either the decoder I defined is being ignored, or I need to explicitly define more of the decode process, but I'm looking for some help to find what the solution might be.

Comment: This works as expected: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/Mr71ZgCbQrahnbbTqkiLSA/5 _(**Scastie** is down for some reason, but if you download the code it works)_

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, this is a good answer.  Now I'm trying to understand why the entire list of case classes needs to have the implicit val *decoder defined.  They have not changed  and it worked without them in the case that did not require the transformation from kebab-case

Comment: Because you where probably using automatic derivation which can be a bad idea.